# How to typetext in textarea which have dynamic element?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I want to input text in textarea, but unable to find the element since the id is dynamic, and if I use class, element is visible. Here's [Snippet Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maTCK.png) of the element, here's the [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGv18.png).
I wrote this on my script

```js
let textArea = Selector('.block-card list-group-item text-card col-xs-12').find('textarea')
await t
    .typeText(textArea, 'Hai...')
```

I got error:

```
The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

> | Selector('.block-card list-group-item text-card col-xs-12')
  |   .find('textarea')
```

I also use

```js
let textArea = Selector('.hwt-container').find('textarea').withAttribute('class','text-card-text')
```

Still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [hasClass](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html#members-common-across-all-nodes) method instead of withAttribute.

**UPDATE:**

Here's my sample test case:

`60986279.html`

```
<div id="cardList" class="list-group">
<div id="1585" class="block-card list-group-item text card col-xs-12">
<div class="hwt-container">
<div class="hwt-backgdrop">
<textarea id="1585" maxlength="640" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Enter Text" style="overflow: hidden; break-word;" class="text-card-text maxlengthBadge form-control"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

`60986279.js`

```
import { Selector} from 'testcafe';

fixture('fixture')
    .page('file:///path/60986279.html');

test('test', async t => {
    let textArea = Selector('.block-card').find('textarea')
    await t.typeText(textArea, 'Hai...')
});
```

Comment: I using  let textArea = await Selector('.list-group').find('.block-card').find('.list-group-item .form-group').find('div').find('.hwt-container').find('textarea').hasClass('text-card-text maxlengthBadge form-control to-autosize hwt-input hwt-content') but got error: Action "selector" argument error:

      Selector is expected to be initialized with a function, CSS selector string, another Selector, node snapshot or a Promise
      returned by a Selector, but boolean was passed.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I've updated my answer with a sample test case and it passes. My attempts to replicate the described behavior were unsuccessful. Please update my sample with your complete markup if my sample does not work in your code.

Comment: I got error with your sample: 1) The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.

Comment: I run my sample using this testcafe of version 1.8.3 as follows: `testcafe chrome 60986270.js` and the test is passed. You can [debug your page](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/debugging.html#client-side-debugging) (and my sample) to check the web page state and what elements are available.